# Save json or multidimentional array to DB (flat)

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, drag-and-drop, nested-lists

I have a nested drag and drop list which return json formattet string. I can run php serialize, json_decode, etc. on this string. But I stuck at saving the hierarchy in DB.

Example of returned output:

[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":2,"children":[{"id":4},{"id":7},{"id":8}]},{"id":3}]},{"id":5},{"id":6}]

...or...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 8
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
        )

)
```

I want to save this output to a DB-structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rang` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain, how the DB-Fieldnames match to the JSON-Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
<?php
$jsonString = '[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":2,"children":[{"id":4},{"id":7},{"id":8}]},{"id":3}]},{"id":5},{"id":6}]';
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);

function parseJsonArray($jsonArray, $parentID = 0)
{
  $return = array();
  foreach ($jsonArray as $subArray) {
     $returnSubSubArray = array();
     if (isset($subArray['children'])) {
       $returnSubSubArray = parseJsonArray($subArray['children'], $subArray['id']);
     }
     $return[] = array('id' => $subArray['id'], 'parentID' => $parentID);
     $return = array_merge($return, $returnSubSubArray);
  }

  return $return;
}

var_dump(parseJsonArray($jsonArray));
```

You should get array like this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array (
    [id] => 1 
    [parentID] => 0 
  ) 
  [1] => Array (
    [id] => 2
    [parentID] => 1 
  ) 
  // ETC.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Eigher you set up a Nested Sets Model on mysql [German Tutorial for Nested Sets](http://www.klempert.de/nested_sets/), what might be best way or you can store the request string in your DB (but beware, you can't do any actions on mysql-side ...)

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you use the ID in you JSON-Data as the primary-key in your DB. So you dont have to deal with LAST_INSERT_ID.

```
function storeTree(array $treeList) {
    // Optional: Start DB-Transaction
    try {
        storeList($treeList);
        // Optional: Commit DB-Transaction
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        // Optional: Rollback DB-Transaction
    }

}

function storeList(array $list, $parentId=null) {
    foreach($list as $child) {
        storeChild($child, $parentId);
    }
}

function storeChild(array $childData, $parentId=null) {
    $childId = $childData['id'];
    $children = isset($childData['children']) ? (array) $childData['children'] : array();

    // Add a new dataset: `id` = $childId, `parent_id` = $parentId

    storeList($children, $childId);
}

storeTree($youJsonData);
```

This code is not tested and may contain errors...